# Exception java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem while deleting a file from HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

In spark cluster, I am running a loop and I want to delete the file created in the last but one iteration. 
Here is my code:

```
val numIter=10
var iteration = 0
while (iteration < numIter) {    
  val b=iteration-2
  if(b >= 0){
     val fs=FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
     val edgpath="Mypath" + b
     fs.delete(new Path(edgpath),true)
  }

  graph.vertices.saveAsObjectFile("Mypath_" + iteration)
}
```

When I run this code I am getting this exception

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem, value: 
DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_668411888_1, 
ugi=vadivel (auth:SIMPLE)]])
    - field (class: $iw, name: fs, type: class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@49637e15)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@71a504e5)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@7bc7d6dc)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@329e5b56)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@cf66fb8)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@77abf7b7)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@17b267fc)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@74e14791)
    - field (class: $line17.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $line17.$read, $line17.$read@56f66c33)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $line17$read, type: class $line17.$read)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@45674a70)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@47d9f051)
    - field (class: $anonfun$3, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $anonfun$3, <function3>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphOps$$anonfun$13, name: mapFunc$1, type: interface scala.Function3)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphOps$$anonfun$13, <function3>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.VertexRDDImpl$$anonfun$3, name: f$4, type: interface scala.Function3)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.VertexRDDImpl$$anonfun$3, <function2>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
at  org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
... 57 more
```

Please share your ideas on how to resolve this error

Comment: This is interesting. Can't see how the FileSystem (`fs`) object may need to be serialized. Is `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem` the runtime class of `fs` (`System.out.println(fs.getClass())`)?

Comment: It is the class of org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

Comment: you should show the code for " some rdd based on some computation"

Comment: @Ashwini I understand that's the FQCN for `FileSystem`. Just wanted to confirm that it's the `fs` variable that Spark is complaining about. What does `System.out.println(fs.getClass())` output? Also, can you please post the full stacktrace, including cause throwables?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele yes you are right. It outputs class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Sorry it is a mistake. I am saving the vertices of my graph. In my code I am doing pagerank computation

Comment: Is this code executed in some spark worker node?

Comment: If that is the case, can't your function just return the paths to be deleted and then remove them outside the cluster?

Comment: @Euge I would like to delete it on the flow while the iterations are happening. I don't want to do the deletion manually

Comment: @Ashwini I mean, not *manually* delete the files, but *outside* the spark transformation (is this function passed to a map over an rdd? can you provide more context?). Because the problem might be that spark wants to serialize objects being passed to worker nodes.